# Is custom receiver required for playing H264/AAC video stream on Chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have an IOS and Android app that can currently play video from a remote server. The remote server sends H264/AAC stream which can be played on the IOS or Android device.

I am working on supporting casting it to a Chromecast device and using the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial) I was able to create the route button to select the chromecast.

My question is, in order to play this stream, do I need to create a custom receiver app to run on the chromecast (and get it whitelisted etc) or is there a default "media player" running on chromecast that can be used to play the stream? I can send a authenticated URL (so there is no custom authentication etc required)

Comment: I was able to use the simple receiver that came with the sample app and was able to cast video.

Comment: you still have to put the receiver.html that came with sample app on your server right? Did you have to do anything special to the receiver in order to make it work with the remote server. Also, any changes you made to the android app to work with cast. I am at a point where my device can detect cast device and tries to connect. I am wondering whether I have to host the receiver html file somewhere in a server and get it whitelisted, put the APP_ID given by Google in the receever file and the app itself? Your insight will be helpful.

Comment: yes. I just used the same receiver.html that was in the sample app. Main thing is that your device has to be whitelisted and use the "live" link's APP_ID. What error code does it spit when you try to start session? if it is not whitelisted, you will see a -4

Comment: Yes, it is -4. I guess then I have to whitelist the device. Thanks for clarification, it helped a lot. Can you tell me the purpose of the receiver html file? Google has not done a good job in explaining.

Comment: The receiver file is the "target" that uses the google's API to allows it to listen when your "sender" app connects and sends data. The purpose of whitelisting (based on my understanding) is a to allow the sender to "lookup" the receiver based on the APP ID provided by google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app currently would need it's own Receiver to be used by both iOS and Android.  There is a default Receiver for Android if you only use the Android MediaRouter API's.  There is no equivalent functionality for iOS.

That said, you can just use the simple sample Receiver that comes with the sample app.